# while loop within while loop

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

`"hello"` is printed by `puts` only three times. It is supposed to be printed six times, isn't it?

```
i = 0
j = 0
while(i != 2)
    while(j != 3)
            puts "hello"
            j += 1
    end
i += 1
end
```

Comment: Note that in Ruby there generally are better ways to do traditional `for` and `while` loops. For example: `2.times { 3.times { puts "hello" } }` is equivalent to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `j` to `0` outside the inner `while` loop.

```
i = 0
j = 0
while(i != 2)
    while(j != 3)
            puts "hello"
            j += 1
    end
# this is needed, as inside the upper loop, you made j to 3 after 3 iteration.
# thus you need to reset it to 0 again, to start again 3 times iteration.
j = 0 
i += 1
end
# >> hello
# >> hello
# >> hello
# >> hello
# >> hello
# >> hello
```

---

Better is -

```
i = 0
while(i != 2)
  j = 0
  while(j != 3)
    puts "hello"
    j += 1
  end
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: Wow ! thank you for your fast answer! I feel a bit stupid but I wont forget it :p

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier for you if you work with loop {} - even though you have to keep track of the counter yourself, I find it much easier to understand instantly than using while, or x.times which also works fine.